# HTML form POST method transformed into GET method

Tags: php, html

I have a very mysterious problem make every `<form method="POST">` not working on a single file, for x reason the POST method get transformed into a GET method making the form element useless. I don't know if it's authorized but i make a video about this "problem" [here](https://streamable.com/7pggj6) since no one really understand what i'm meanning.

If you have potential idea why it is working on the test folder but not on the admin folder even if both code are the same please let me know it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="php/SetSanction.php">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); gap: 16px;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="daySelect">Day:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="daySelect" id="daySelect">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              <option value="19">19</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="21">21</option>
              <option value="22">22</option>
              <option value="23">23</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">26</option>
              <option value="27">27</option>
              <option value="28">28</option>
              <option value="29">29</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="monthSelect">Month:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="monthSelect" id="monthSelect">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              <option value="19">19</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="21">21</option>
              <option value="22">22</option>
              <option value="23">23</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">26</option>
              <option value="27">27</option>
              <option value="28">28</option>
              <option value="29">29</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="yearSelect">Year:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="yearSelect" id="yearSelect">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              <option value="19">19</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="21">21</option>
              <option value="22">22</option>
              <option value="23">23</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">26</option>
              <option value="27">27</option>
              <option value="28">28</option>
              <option value="29">29</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Reason</label>
        <textarea name="reasonInput" id="reasonInput" class="form-control" placeholder="..." rows="3" maxlength="400"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <input type="submit" value="Set">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the PHP File (SetSanction.php)

```
<?php
print_r($_POST); // THIS ARRAY SHOULD BE EMPTY BECAUSE POST NOT WORKING

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') /*NOT WORK BECAUSE IT'S NOT POST REQ*/ {
    $daySelected = $_POST['daySelect'];
    $monthSelected = $_POST['monthSelect'];
    $yearSelected = $_POST['yearSelect'];
    $reasonInput = $_POST['reasonInput'];

    echo "Day: " . $daySelected . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Does your console or network tab show any info. Can you include that info here

Comment: What do you mean by "console"?

Comment: browser console

Comment: The console is empty

Comment: Are you using any php framework?

Comment: Are you using htaccess to rewrite the urls? Because, in the video, the admin form sends request to `admin/php/SetSanction` and test sends its to `php/SetSanction.php`. Notice the file extension in the URL. Sometimes, while rewriting urls, forms may break.

Comment: Aos, bootstrap, PHP-Auth and bulletproof. I'm with the php version 8.1

Comment: I already have many form even with htaccess rules and it's working fine, do you really think this should be the problem?

Comment: Not sure, but you can try disabling the rewrite rules. It's worth a try :)

Comment: Wow! i don't even think it would be this! Huge thanks! You can post the answer for others know about this problem too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are rewriting the urls to remove the extensions, this will break the form because the form action won't be a valid url.

Best option would be to exclude the form action url / file from the `.htaccess` file.

Something like this in your case:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php/SetSanction\.php$`